# как войти с уже созданного пользователя?

Tags: windows, users

сегодня вместо входа в систему получил ошибку о том что Windows не может войти в пользователя yanis, и тогда пошла подготовка Windows, после которой создался новый пользователь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что можно сделать чтоб система снова входила с основного юзера?

Comment: 1) Попробовать указать папку профиля(в реестре). 2) Попробовать почистить реестр пользователя(внутри старой папки), восстановить права доступа на папку и вернутся к шагу 1 :)

Comment: вы хотите войти с локальной учетной записи

Comment: да, я хочу войти с уже созданной локальной учетной записи

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в Компьютер\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-511878611-3447774420-388721161 в ProfileImagePath итак написан путь: C:\Users\yanis, а вот касательно 2 пункта я не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, как почистить реестр внутри сатрой папки и как востановить права доступа на папку?

Comment: Внутри папки старого профиля файлы NTUSER.dat - удалить их(переместить из этой папки), и скопировать на их место или у defaultuser или из вашей "новой" папки профиля

Comment: Найди `MicrosoftFixit50446.msi`.